# Can I change the colour of a country map plotted in R using

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors

I have plotted the map of South America using

library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

```
p=c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Uruguay", "Paraguay", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Venezuela",
         "Colombia", "Bolivia")

mp<-map_data("world", region=p) 

mlola <- mp %>%  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarize(mlo= mean(long), mla=mean(lat))


ggplot(mapa_paises,aes( x= long, y = lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
  geom_polygon( )+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA))
```

Now, I need to plot it using a blue scale, using [Bluges](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/colors-in-r). I have tried to add it as follows:

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)



    p=c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Uruguay", "Paraguay", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Venezuela",
             "Colombia", "Bolivia")
    
    mp<-map_data("world", region=p) 
    
    mlola <- mp %>%  group_by(region) %>% 
      summarize(mlo= mean(long), mla=mean(lat))
    
    
    ggplot(mapa_paises,aes( x= long, y = lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
      geom_polygon(aes(color="Bluges"))+
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA))
```

This, however,doesn't seem to do anything. I have checked the help of [geom_poligon](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_polygon.html), but I cannot see how to do it.

Comment: did you try the `color` argument outside `aes`?

Comment: Yes, I recieve `Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_polygon, x$x, x$y, index) : 
  invalid color name 'Bluges'`

Comment: Try its hexcode and see what you get

Comment: `geom_polygon(color=FF5733)+` also returns an error, I'm afraid

Comment: You have to put FF573 in quotation marks like this "#FF5733" now try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```r
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

p=c("Brazil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Uruguay", "Paraguay", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Venezuela",
    "Colombia", "Bolivia")

mp<-map_data("world", region=p) 

mlola <- mp %>%  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarize(mlo= mean(long), mla=mean(lat))

#changed the dataset to mp
ggplot(mp,aes( x= long, y = lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=region),
               color = "black")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA))
#> Warning in RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal): n too large, allowed maximum for palette Blues is 9
#> Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This palette ([Blues](https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=Blues&n=9)) is not advised because it has just 9 levels, and we are trying to plot 10 countries.